# How to unlock advanced tab in phoenix bios?

Tags: bios

I have a laptop with Windows 8.1pro 64bit on it. I tried to downgrade it to Windows 7, but I got a blue screen mentioning I have to disable caching and shadowing in my bios (it was a suggested solution, not sure if it was the only problem).

To do so, you need to have an advanced tab in bios which by default is locked and invisible in phoenix bios.

Does anyone know how to unlock the advanced tab in phoenix bios?

There is a similar link which also haven't got any answer yet: https://superuser.com/questions/840843/how-to-unlock-the-hidden-locked-settings-in-bios-on-Linux

Comment: What make/model laptop do you have?

Comment: S410P ideapad lenovo

Comment: Ask here https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Forum-Phoenix-Unlocking-Requests

Comment: do you refer users here to different forums to ask their question? then whats the point of this website? you can refer windows questions to windows forum, kali questions to kali forum,... am asking it here! thnx

Comment: Because unlocking your BIOS requires modifying it which is a specialised task particular to the version of the BIOS you have on your particular model laptop, and that's where the experts hang out.

Comment: i did create a thread there anyway. thnx